# Can't find attribute

Tags: object, attributes, python-3.7

I have a card deck and a card. I'm sending the card as an argument and want to find it in the deck and remove it.

The code I have looks like this:

```py
class Card:
    suitList = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
    rankList = ["0", "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
    "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]

    def __init__(self, rank=0, suit=0):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        for suit in range(4):
            for rank in range(1, 14):
                self.cards.append(Card(rank, suit))

    def removeCard(self, card):
        if card in self.cards:
            self.cards.remove(card)
            return True
        else:
            return False

deck = Deck()
print(deck.removeCard(Card(1,0)))
```

Every time I run this program it prints 'False' and can't find the card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is Python doesn't know how to compare the `Card` for equality. To fix this, we need to make `__eq__` magic function, where we compare actual `Card` to other `Card` ([doc about Python's Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__)):

```
class Card:
    suitList = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
    rankList = ["0", "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
    "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]

    def __init__(self, rank=0, suit=0):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    # THIS IS NEEDED FOR COMPARING VARIOUS TYPES OF CARDS:
    def __eq__(self, other_card):
        return self.rank == other_card.rank and self.suit == other_card.suit

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Card({}, {})'.format(self.rank, self.suit)

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        for suit in range(4):
            for rank in range(1, 14):
                self.cards.append(Card(rank, suit))

    def removeCard(self, card):
        print('Before remove: ', len(self.cards))
        if card in self.cards:
            self.cards.remove(card)
            print('After remove: ', len(self.cards))
            return True
        else:
            return False

deck = Deck()
print(deck.removeCard(Card(1,0)))
```

Prints:

```
Before remove:  52
After remove:  51
True
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, `for rank in range(1,14)` is wrong, try changing it to `range(14)`. The latter will include 0 which is an index in rankList.

Also in order for `card in self.cards` to work, you must define **eq** inside Card:

```
def __eq__(self, other: card) -> bool:
    return self.rank == other.rank and self.suit == other.suit
```

In order to use python's standard operators or keywords on an class object, you need to add the functionality yourself. This concept is called operator overloading.

Comment: Thnks for the reply. The reason to why I used range(1, 14) is that I wanted rankList[1] = 1 and not rankList[1] = 2 and so on, the '0' is never used.

Comment: I see, makes sense now. I was thinking as a programmer more so than a normal person. I had forgotten 0 wasn't in the deck! Another way if you want to save memory is just get rid of the zero in the list and make it range(0,13), but it's up to you. Programmers count from 0 after all.